# Django: Order query set by comment count

Tags: django, comments, django-queryset, django-aggregation

Very simple... I am using Django 1.4.1, and need to order a queryset by the inverse of the number of comments on it.  I am using the Django comment framework, and have attempted to use the .annotate(comment_count = Count('comment') structure recommended in other answers...  I get 'comment' doesn't resolve to a field error.

I've also tried the 0.3.1 version of django-generic-aggregate, which throws a database error, so that's out.

```
Photo.objects.filter(galleries=gallery).annotate(comment_count=Count('comments')).order_by('-comment_count')[(page-1)*RESULTS_PER_PAGE:page*RESULTS_PER_PAGE]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant contents of the `Photo` model

Comment: I'm confused... The comments system is built into Django.  It attaches to any model.  The Photo model structure itself is irrelevant, I could as well be trying to order Widgets by comment count.

Comment: Ignore my comment.  I didn't realize the commenting app uses a `GenericForeignKey` and so doesn't require an explicit reference relating your `Photo` model.  You might find that what you're trying to do isn't currently possible.  See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations-and-aggregation)

Comment: Hi Austin,  Yeah, I saw that it's not supported natively.  I'm pretty sure that is what django-generic-aggregate is supposed to fix.  I'm looking for a way to accomplish the task, even if it's not pretty.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Put the function under Photo model

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    .........

    def orders(self):
        //filter first the highest count of comments
        aggregate = Photo.objects.aggregate(comment_count=Count('comments'))
        return aggregate['comment_count'] + 1
```

Then you can call it like this in view:

```
comments = Photo.objects.filter(galleries=gallery).orders()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Catherine!  I'm confused though, I'm trying to order my queryset by the comment_count...  Will this method do that?  (is orders a magic method name?)

Comment: I have a badge model and I need to get the ranking of the users based on the points so I did that way and it works. I don't know in your side, just try. If not working we will try another until your problem is solve :)